# Keyword not supported: 'mssqllocaldb; attachdbfilename'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I got this error when I connect to my db and my db is in Azure cloud. My connect string didn't have "attachdbfilename". Could any one can help me to fix this issue?

My connection string:

```
<connectionStrings> 
<add name="TaichungBusEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TaichungBus.csdl|res://*/Models.TaichungBus.ssdl|res://*/Models.TaichungBus.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=cibigdatacsp.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:XXXX;initial catalog=XXXXXXX_XXX_XXX;user id=XXXXX;password=XXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: further explain: I can run my website on IIS in my server normally. But other people who want to connect to my website to search some information. my website always display error message "Keyword not supported: 'mssqllocaldb; attachdbfilename'."....

Comment: Could you try to copy the connection string from your Azure portal and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Try to [remote debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-debug-cloud-services-virtual-machines) on your cloud service to check the connectionstring.

Comment: Thanks~I find out it is my browser problem. Thanks~